# Getting a value from object

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel, laravel-4

hello people is the output...

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [LAST_INSERT_ID()] => 213 ) )
```

i just want to get a value of `LAST_INSERT_ID` i have already tried...(max_id is object name)

```
echo  $max_id[0]->[LAST_INSERT_ID()];
```

but i get an error

```
syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

I am using laravel frame work... any ways to fix this?

Comment: and your object name is? O.o

Comment: try this $arr[0]->LAST_INSERT_ID();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$obj = (array)$arr[0]; // convert the object to array
$value = $obj['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];
```

OR

```
$prop = 'LAST_INSERT_ID()';
$value = $arr[0]->$prop;
```

OR

```
$arr[0]->{'LAST_INSERT_ID()'};
```